# Trouble with timezone - Plesk/Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, plesk

i got problem with timezone. I set timezone on VPS for **Europe/Warsaw (UTC+2)**, I set in VPS managment system Plesk timezone for **Europe/Warsaw** and when I use for example **time()** in PHP, that return not correct time (-2 hours). What to do?

Comment: A Unix timestamp is *always* in UTC, which is because the timestamp is just a number and has no way to encode a timezone. Use [DateTime](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateTimeZone](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) if you want to deal with timezones properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really nice comment on PHP's documentation site, because this information isn't in the documentation but should answer your question immediately.

> The function time() returns always timestamp that is timezone independent (=UTC). 
>   For more information take a look [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php#100220.).

As Sammitch already commented, you shouldn't rely on the `time()` function. There is a handy Class called `DateTime` which you can use.

Below a few Examples:

```
$objDateTime = new DateTime();
//retrieve current Timezone
echo $objDateTime->getTimezone()->getName();
```

if your timezone here isn't `Europe/Warsaw` you have two possibilites to change them:

1. change it in your php.ini
   There is a section called `[Date]` in your php.ini and the corresponding setting is called `date.timezone`. 
   Just set it to `date.timezone = Europe/Warsaw`.
2. you can add a `Timezone` to your current `DateTime` Object.

This would look like:

```
$objDateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Warsaw'));
echo $objDateTime->format('d.m.Y H:i:s');
```

And that's it.